# Hilt injection of application context with jetpack compose correct structure with MVVM

Tags: mvvm, viewmodel, dagger-hilt

How can I provide context to my RepositoryImpl with such structure?

I know that using context in DataViewModel could provide to memory leaks.

But how can I provide correct structure?

Approximate structure:

```
fun DataViewModel: ViewModel() {
  // here I need to use RepositoryImpl
  fun getUser(){
    viewModelScope.launch {
      RepositoryImpl.getData().collect{user -> _user.value = user}
    }
  }
}
```

repository interface:

```
interface Repository {
   fun getData(): Flow<User>
}

class RepositoryImpl (
) : Repository {
 override fun getData(): Flow<User> = flow {}  // here I need application context to work with my data base
}
```